# Is it a good way to use java.util.concurrent.FutureTask?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, futuretask

First of all, I must say that I am quite new to the API java.util.concurrent, so maybe what I am doing is completely wrong.

What do I want to do?

I have a Java application that basically runs 2 separate processing (called *myFirstProcess*, *mySecondProcess*), but these processing must be run at the same time.

So, I tried to do that:

```
public void startMyApplication() {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    FutureTask<Object> futureOne = new FutureTask<Object>(myFirstProcess);
    FutureTask<Object> futureTwo = new FutureTask<Object>(mySecondProcess);
    executor.execute(futureOne);
    executor.execute(futureTwo);
    while (!(futureOne.isDone() && futureTwo.isDone())) {
        try {
            // I wait until both processes are finished.
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    logger.info("Processing finished");
    executor.shutdown();
    // Do some processing on results
    ...
}
```

*myFirstProcess* and *mySecondProcess* are classes that implements `Callable<Object>`, and where all their processing is made in the call() method.

It is working quite well but I am not sure that it is the correct way to do that.
Is a good way to do what I want? If not, can you give me some hints to enhance my code (and still keep it as simple as possible).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You'd be better off using the `get()` method.

```
futureOne.get();
futureTwo.get();
```

Both of which wait for notification from the thread that it finished processing, this saves you the busy-wait-with-timer you are now using which is not efficient nor elegant.

As a bonus, you have the API `get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` which allows you to define a maximum time for the thread to sleep and wait for a response, and otherwise continues running.

See the [Java API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) for more info.

Comment: So instead of Callable he should implement Future or should he implement both?

Comment: Oh sorry, I was confused by your link. FutureTask has .get() method.

Comment: The answer that talks about using a CompletionService is a far better one than this one.

Answer (score 18):

The uses of `FutureTask` above are tolerable, but definitely not idiomatic. You're actually wrapping an *extra* `FutureTask` around the one you submitted to the `ExecutorService`. Your `FutureTask` is treated as a `Runnable` by the `ExecutorService`. Internally, it wraps your `FutureTask`-as-`Runnable` in a new `FutureTask` and returns it to you as a `Future<?>`.

Instead, you should submit your `Callable<Object>` instances to a [`CompletionService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html). You drop two `Callable`s in via `submit(Callable<V>)`, then turn around and call `CompletionService#take()` twice (once for each submitted `Callable`). Those calls will block until one and then the other submitted tasks are complete.

Given that you already have an `Executor` in hand, construct a new [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) around it and drop your tasks in there. Don't spin and sleep waiting; `CompletionService#take()` will block until either one of your tasks are complete (either finished running or canceled) or the thread waiting on `take()` is interrupted.

Answer (score 17):

Yuval's solution is fine.  As an alternative you can also do this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool();
FutureTask<Object> futureOne = new FutureTask<Object>(myFirstProcess);
FutureTask<Object> futureTwo = new FutureTask<Object>(mySecondProcess);
executor.execute(futureOne);
executor.execute(futureTwo);
executor.shutdown();
try {
  executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  // interrupted
}
```

What is the advantage of this approach?  There's not a lot of difference really except that this way you stop the executor accepting any more tasks (you can do that the other way too).  I tend to prefer this idiom to that one though.

Also, if either get() throws an exception you may end up in a part of your code that assumes both tasks are done, which might be bad.

Comment: "if either get() throws an exception you may end up in a part of your code that assumes both tasks are done" surely that's only if you swallow the exception?

Answer (score 7):

You can use invokeall(Colelction....) method

```
package concurrent.threadPool;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class InvokeAll {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        List<Future<java.lang.String>> futureList = service.invokeAll(Arrays.asList(new Task1<String>(),new Task2<String>()));

        System.out.println(futureList.get(1).get());
        System.out.println(futureList.get(0).get());
    }

    private static class Task1<String> implements Callable<String>{

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * 10);
            return (String) "1000 * 5";
        }

    }

    private static class Task2<String> implements Callable<String>{

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * 2);
            int i=3;
            if(i==3)
                throw new RuntimeException("Its Wrong");
            return (String) "1000 * 2";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You may want to use a [CyclicBarrier](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) if you are interested in starting the threads at the same time, or waiting for them to finish and then do some further processing.
See the javadoc for more information.

Comment: I am not sure that I will need to use the specificities of the CyclicBarrier, but it is a quite interesting class...

Answer (score 2):

If your futureTasks are more then 2, please consider `[ListenableFuture][1]`.

> When several operations should begin as soon as another operation
>   starts -- "**fan-out**" -- ListenableFuture just works: it triggers all of
>   the requested callbacks. With slightly more work, we can "**fan-in**," or
>   trigger a ListenableFuture to get computed as soon as several other
>   futures have all finished.