# Android Future vs FutureTask

Tags: java, android, concurrency, future, futuretask

Is there any reason to use one over the other? They seem to both do the same thing in different ways. I can see that `FutureTask` is more extensible, but for a simple task where I want to return a future to get a value from later, is there a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a real benefit of the default implementation of FutureTask. I think the benefit comes when you extend it and override the callback methods according to you requirements.

If you use the default implementation of FutureTask, wrapping a Callable when sending a new task using ExecutorService's execute(). As [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1780411/2017375) says, it's like wrapping a FutureTask with another FutureTask.